# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/service/invoker/Invoker

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I created a client to consume a webservice. The client code is:

```
package cliente;

import java.util.List;

import handler.HeaderHandler;
import webservice.BoletinOficial;
import webservice.BoletinOficialService;
import petanuncio.PeticionAnuncio;
import respanuncio.RespuestaAnuncio;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.binding.DefaultBindingImpl;

import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Cliente {

/**
 * Main
 * @param args
 */
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String endpointURL = "";
  try {


       BoletinOficialService service = new BoletinOficialService();

       BoletinOficial proxy = service.getBoletinOficialSoap11();


//rest of code

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

The problem is when running the program and get the following error anc cannot even create "service":

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at webservice.BoletinOficialService.<init>(BoletinOficialService.java:46)
    at cliente.Cliente.main(Cliente.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/service/invoker/Invoker
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.Invoker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

This class and others were created via wsimport from a wsdl file, althoug I don't think this is related to the error I am getting.
The class org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl is in cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.1.jar file whis is added as referece to the project.

[image: This is the project structure]

[image: These are the libraries]

Is there anything I am missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the compile dependencies you find at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.1.1

Better, switch to Maven.

Comment: Well, I switched to Maven and at leats the error I described is gone, although I am getting others. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of errors?  There is a webpage about how to configure CXF in Maven at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html Next to cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws, you also have to declare the cxf-rt-transports-http dependency and optionally the cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty dependency.  If you do not use the cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty dependency, you have to use the CXFServlet to configure your web services.

Comment: CXF has sample projects as explained at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html . Check https://cxf.apache.org/source-repository.html how to get the source code of the CXF project. The sample projects can be found there under the folder src/main/release/samples

Comment: Actually the later error was due to cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty dependency, but I added it to Pom.xml and it was fixed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Invoker` is part of the CXF API. Looks like the cxf-api is missing.

If you use maven, add the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Else add the jar to your classpath.

Comment: Clearly, he is not using Maven.  Probably he should.  One thing that Maven solved is managing transitive dependencies.  No need for him to start managing these transitive dependencies himself.

Comment: I am not using Maven. I have also added the jar (an others) to the classpath via Properties/Java Build Path/Add Variable. Added a folder and then all the jar files and then checked them in "Order and Export" tab. Saved the changes and cleaned and built the project again and run the client with same result: error.

Comment: I tried to change the project type to Maven but started to get severa errors so I wanted to try if I can fix it first.

Comment: I switched to Maven and the error is gone. Many thanks.